# How to include a substring EXCEPT an exact one in middle of REGEX expression?

Tags: regex

### Issue

I'm trying to match 3 groups, where one is conditional

String: **12345-12345-1230**

Group 1: **12345-12345**

Group 2: **-123**

Group 3: **0**

However I only want to match Group 2 if the string is NOT "**-000**". Meaning group 2 will either be blank if that section is '-000' or it will be whatever else those 4 characters are; '-123' '-001', etc.).

Here is the REGEX with it just accepting anything as group 2:
**^(.{5}-.{5})(.{4})([0-9])$**  [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3IQx9I/1)

### What I've tried

Negative Lookahead:

- **^(.{5}-.{5})(?!-000)([0-9])$**
- **^(.{5}-.{5})(.{4}(?!.{4}))([0-9])$**

OR Operator:

- **^(.{5}-.{5})(-000)|(.{4})([0-9])$**
- This is the closest I've come, however I can't get it to work WITH the final condition ([0-9])$. It's also not ideal to have the remove case (-000) as a separate group as the accept case (*not* -000).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```
^(\d{5}-\d{5})(?:-000|(-\d{3}))(\d)$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/l6k2EZ/4).

---

- `^` - Start of line ancor.
- `(` - Open 1st capture group.

  - `\d{5}-\d{5}` - Match 5 digits, an hyphen, and again 5 digits.
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group.
- `(?:` - Open non-capturing group.

  - `-000` - Match "-000" literally.
  - `|` - Pipe symbol used as an or-operator.
  - `(` - Open 2nd capture group.

    - `-\d{3}` - match an hyphen and 3 digits.
    - `)` - Close 2nd capture group.
  - `)` - Close non-capturing group.
- `(` - Open 3rd capture group.

  - `(\d)` - Match a single digit.
  - `)` - Close 3rd capture group.
- `$` - End line ancor.

---

If you want to capture the 2nd group without hypen, then try: `^(\d{5}-\d{5})-(?:000|(\d{3}))(\d)$`

Comment: so can put a non-capture IN a capture group. Okay perfect, thank you sir.

Comment: @JayM, it's reversed really; a capture group in a non-capture group. Enjoy the solution =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`(\d{5}-\d{5})(?!-000)(-\d{3})(0)`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l6k2EZ/2)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I'd like 12345-12345-0000 to still match group 1 (12345-12345) and 3 (0).